# Unset a specific session item based on value inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, session, unset

**Problem:**

I have a session variable that consist of multiple array and each array has a set of values. I wish to unset the specific array that matches the value of a specific variable inside the session array.

**Session construction:**

[image]

**PHP code:**

```
$key = array_search($answers['evaluationnumber'], $_SESSION['stimuli']);

if ($key !== false) {
  unset($_SESSION['stimuli'][$key]);
  $_SESSION['stimuli'] = array_values($_SESSION['stimuli']);
}
```

I have double checked and I get the value `3841` from the variable `$answers['evaluationnumber']`.

**Question:**

How do I start digging into the array list to unset that specific key?

**Desired output:**

To be able to remove an array inside the session array called `stimuli` based on the value given in the variable `$answers['evaluationnumber']`.

Comment: But in the Session construction the key is `evaluationsnumber` not `evaluationnumber`.

Comment: Could yo uhave more than one occurance of the array inside the `$_SESSION['stimuli']` array

Comment: @Azhy I see - how do I search each array to find the one with the evaluationnumber that match the one I have in the variable?

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, it's always only one occurance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check the specific occurance on the session against `$answers['evaluationnumber']` and as you say there will only ever be one occurance of the sub array in `$_SESSION['stimuli']`, this would seem the simplest way.

```
if ( $_SESSION['stimuli'][0]['evaluationsnumber'] == $answers['evaluationnumber'] ) {
    unset($_SESSION['stimuli'][0]);
}
```

Comment: This, however, will remove the entire array and I'm only interested in removing the specific array that matches inside the value of `evaluationsnumber`.

Comment: I admit I am not totally following your requirement now, so I added 2 other possibilities

Comment: I made a clarification that it's the specific array that needs to be unset, so it would be the second of your three examples.

Comment: Removed option 1 and 3. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function for php.

It will take a array and a filter function. 
This filter function will be handed every element of your original array. In there check for your desired key.

If you return `true` in that function the final array will include the element, if `false` it will be excluded. There is a [simple example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#example-6158) in the docs.